# Unable to install vim on a RasPi (Raspbian GNU/Linux 7)

Tags: apt, vim, raspberry-pi

I am trying to install vim onto a RasPi (i.e., Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)), but while executing "sudo apt-get install vim" I am getting an error.  I have tried searching for a solution, but I haven't found anything that seems to help me so far.  I tried the following suggestions from a forum, but it doesn't seem to help.

```
sudo dpkg --force-remove-reinstreq vim
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The following is the output of the command

```
pi@rpi-6f-a4-38 ~ $ sudo apt-get install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  vim-runtime
Suggested packages:
  ctags vim-doc vim-scripts
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vim vim-runtime
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/5,281 kB of archives.
After this operation, 24.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 79130 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking vim-runtime (from .../vim-runtime_2%3a7.3.547-7_all.deb) ...
Adding 'diversion of /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/help.txt to /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/help.txt.vim-tiny by vim-runtime'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting `/usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/help.txt.vim-tiny' with
  different file `/usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/help.txt', not allowed
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/vim-runtime_2%3a7.3.547-7_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 2
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/help.txt by vim-runtime', none removed.
No diversion 'diversion of /usr/share/vim/vim73/doc/tags by vim-runtime', none removed.
Selecting previously unselected package vim.
Unpacking vim (from .../vim_2%3a7.3.547-7_armhf.deb) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/vim-runtime_2%3a7.3.547-7_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Does anyone have a thought on how to resolve/solve this? Thanks in advanced for any help.

Comment: `dpkg -P vim-tiny`

Comment: in my case: `sudo apt-get install vim` 
`Package vim is not available, but is referred to by another package.` on Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.1 (stretch)